# ejs include on click

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to create a dynamically included in an ejs page (using `<%- include('partials/content') %>`) on my node.js project.
Is there a way I can create a variable for the to-be-included page and change it on a button click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume your `partials/content` file includes content like:

```
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
```

A file named `partials/content2`:

```
<h1>consectetur adipiscing elit<h1>
```

Your main template file would wrap the partials content by a `<div>` with the id `result` and include a script file where you select this `<div>` by using `var $result = $('#result');` so you have it in a variable. Then you can register a click handler on your button. On click you request the wished template file and replace the content.

Main template:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="result">
      <%- include partials/content.ejs %>
   </div>
   <button id="change">change</button>
<script>
    var $result = $('#result'); 
    $('#change').click(function() {
       $result.load('/content2');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you need a controller on the backend like:

```
app.get('/content2', function (req, res) { 
    res.render('partials/content2');
});
```

Comment: OK, it's not working for me but for a weird reason - `.load()` isn't working at all. not even when i wiped the entire file clean (except for the jQuery cdn) and just had a div and a load function. and tried to load a simple html file from the same directory

Comment: Of course jquery.js in the <script> tag of the main template has to point to your jQuery file. I updated my answer using jQuery from a CDN.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it. My jQuery link was working, .text() worked fine. For some reason .load() just doesn't work for me...

Comment: I had a typing error in my code, the jQuery selector for the on click function was wrong. Try it again. I just tested it - it works now

Comment: Is it possible the .load() doesn't work if the page I load (i.e. content2) has some ejs content in it (`<%=title%>` and such)?

Comment: no it makes no difference for load. Because load simply receives a HTML file. But it worked before, as you accepted the answer, right? If you want to use variables in content2 then you have to pass them in the content2 controller. And please define "doesn't work".

Comment: Well, Doesn't work simply means clicking on the button doesn't load the page. I don't know what the reason is, but I'll find it. Thank you so far, your answer was a great help.

Comment: ok I see. Always check the console in the browser as well as in the server console for errors. But if  everything worked until you add the variable like <%=title%> then you should check if you pass the values correctly to the template e.g.:
app.get('/content2', function (req, res) { 
    res.render( 'partials/content2',  { title:'this is a test title' } );
});
Also remember that you can open /content2 directly in the browser. It wouldn't make sense that this works and with load() not but you can check it like that. It's just a simple HTTP request.